# how to create a project which support mvn jetty:run?

Tags: jakarta-ee, web-applications, maven, jetty, maven-jetty-plugin

it's better that once mvn archetype:generate is runed, it can do all the things needed to create a project which support mvn jetty:run, but the fact is there are so many templates that i don't even know which one i should choose in order to create a project which support mvn jetty:run, even when -Dfilter option is used, i cannot find the right template to do the thing i want.
so how to how to create a project which support mvn jetty:run quickly?
it's better that i can do all the things simply with one command, that is 
command 1: create projects
command 2: mvn jetty:run to run this web application:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Maven Jetty plugin doc:

> In order to run Jetty on a webapp project which is structured
>   according to the usual Maven defaults (resources in
>   `${basedir}/src/main/webapp`, classes in
>   `${project.build.outputDirectory}` and the `web.xml` descriptor at
>   `${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml`, you don't need to
>   configure anything.
>
> Simply type:
>
> `mvn jetty:run`
>
> This will start Jetty running on port 8080 and serving your project.

So you need to use the `jee6-basic-archetype` (number 414) which will generate the required folder structure.

More information about configuring the plugin is available [in the doc](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Maven+Jetty+Plugin).

Comment: seems there are lots of archetype which support jetty:run, so how to know which one is best?